# how to fix error NativeAnimatedModule on react native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-share

I got this error after installing the `react-native-share` & `react-native-view-shot` library

```
Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code: {"18939":{"module":"NativeAnimatedModule","method":"startAnimatingNode"},"18944"
```

the effect is that the application becomes slow in response when navigating

Answer (score 0):

Similar Issue from Github https://github.com/alexZajac/react-native-skeleton-content-nonexpo/issues/41 maybe help you.

Comment: that's different, my error is about `NativeAnimatedModule` but the error in the link you attached is the error about the `ReanimatedModule` module

Answer (score 0):

This code has a problem with the animation controller that responds with scrolling movement, which causes a memory leak in the app.
If you are using hooks such as 'useEffect' or 'useCallback,' make sure to check if the `cleanup` is properly done.